# potentially corrupted microsd card after computer shut down during a transfer, not automounting

Tags: usb, mount, xubuntu, fstab, automount

My microsd card no longer automounts when i plug it in. I can manually mount it via sudo and reformat it and it still shows in fstab:

```
Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 250085375 250083328 119.3G  b W95 FAT32
```

when i run `dmesg` i get

```
[   25.672188] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[   25.825200] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0741, bcdDevice= 2.20
[   25.825205] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[   25.825208] usb 1-4: Product: USB Storage
[   25.825211] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Generic
[   25.826940] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   25.827115] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-4:1.0
[   26.850090] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   0220 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[   26.850793] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   27.273553] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 250085376 512-byte logical blocks: (128 GB/119 GiB)
[   27.274541] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   27.274545] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[   27.275490] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   27.275497] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   30.203737] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[   30.203742] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Aborted Command [current] 
[   30.203746] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Data phase CRC error detected
[   30.203751] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[   30.203753] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 0
[   30.203760] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[   30.207818] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[   30.207827] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[   30.210722]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[   30.213614] sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Is there anyway to fix the card or is it dead?

Comment: Why is your microSD card in fstab?

Answer (score 0):

From dmesg seems like is unable to read the partition table, so let's recreate it. // Are comments and not part of the commands

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb //Here you're using fdisk utility on /dev/sdb disk 
d //d stands for delete partition
g //g is for recreating GPT table
n //n stands for new
p //p stands for primary partition
ENTER //Press enter key
ENTER
ENTER
w //w means write changes on disk
sudo mkfs.ext -F 32 -I /dev/sdb1 //Command that formats the partition you created in EXT32, must be run outside fdisk
```

After that if you want to add it in fstab, first grab the new UUID:
sudo blkid /dev/sdb1

And add an entry in /etc/fstab like this:

```
UUID=(UUID) /folder/where/to/automount vfat defaults 0 0
```

Comment: what does the ENTER mean

Comment: ``` ➜  ~ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.32).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
➜  ~ sudo fdisk /dev/sdb

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.32).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): d       
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.


```

Comment: Command (m for help): g
Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: CCA0EBF6-77A7-BB49-AD31-E24E35992169).

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (2048-250085342, default 2048): 
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-250085342, default 250085342): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 119.3 GiB.

Comment: Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdb: 119.3 GiB, 128043712512 bytes, 250085376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CCA0EBF6-77A7-BB49-AD31-E24E35992169

Device     Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 250085342 250083295 119.3G Linux filesystem

Comment: Command (m for help): ENTER
E: unknown command

Command (m for help): 


Command (m for help): 


Command (m for help): 


Command (m for help): w

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.

➜  ~ 
sudo mkfs.ext -F 32 -I /dev/sdb1
sudo: mkfs.ext: command not found
➜  ~ 
sudo mkfs -F 32 -I /dev/sdb1 
mkfs.ext2: invalid inode size - /dev/sdb1

Comment: @GreggHorton ENTER is the Enter Key on your keyboard. I also assumed that you knew sudo mkfs.ext command must be run outside fdisk. For a more clear explanation see the fixes to the answer.